# SQL Query not producing 'Disabled' jobs within the results, alongside 'Failed' jobs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following code for a SQL Query I'm working on..

```
DECLARE @Date datetime
SET @Date = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))

DECLARE @jobHistory TABLE
(
      job_id                UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    , success               INT
    , cancel                INT
    , fail                  INT
    , retry                 INT
    , last_execution_id     INT
    , last_duration         CHAR(8)
    , last_execution_start  DATETIME
);

WITH lastExecution
AS
(
    SELECT job_id
    , MAX(instance_id) AS last_instance_id
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory
WHERE step_id = 0
GROUP BY job_id
)

INSERT INTO @jobHistory
SELECT sjh.job_id
    , SUM(CASE WHEN sjh.run_status = 1 AND step_id = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)     AS success
    , SUM(CASE WHEN sjh.run_status = 3 AND step_id = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)     AS cancel
    , SUM(CASE WHEN sjh.run_status = 0 AND step_id = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)     AS fail
    , SUM(CASE WHEN sjh.run_status = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS retry
    , MAX(CASE WHEN sjh.step_id = 0 THEN instance_id ELSE NULL END)     last_execution_id
    , SUBSTRING(CAST(MAX(CASE WHEN le.job_id IS NOT NULL THEN     sjh.run_duration ELSE NULL END) + 1000000 AS VARCHAR(7)),2,2) + ':' 
            + SUBSTRING(CAST(MAX(CASE WHEN le.job_id IS NOT NULL THEN     sjh.run_duration ELSE NULL END) + 1000000 AS VARCHAR(7)),4,2) + ':' 
            + SUBSTRING(CAST(MAX(CASE WHEN le.job_id IS NOT NULL THEN     sjh.run_duration ELSE NULL END) + 1000000 AS VARCHAR(7)),6,2)
            AS last_duration
    , MAX(CASE WHEN le.last_instance_id IS NOT NULL THEN 
        CONVERT(datetime, RTRIM(run_date)) 
        + ((run_time / 10000 *  3600) 
        + ((run_time % 10000) / 100 * 60) 
        + (run_time  % 10000) % 100) / (86399.9964)
      ELSE '1900-01-01' END) AS last_execution_start 
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory AS sjh
LEFT JOIN lastExecution     AS le
    ON sjh.job_id = le.job_id
   AND sjh.instance_id = le.last_instance_id
GROUP BY sjh.job_id;

DECLARE @weekDay TABLE (
      mask          INT
    , maskValue     VARCHAR(32)
);

INSERT INTO @weekDay
SELECT 1, 'Sunday'      UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Monday'      UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Tuesday'     UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 'Wednesday'   UNION ALL
SELECT 16, 'Thursday'   UNION ALL
SELECT 32, 'Friday'     UNION ALL
SELECT 64, 'Saturday';

WITH myCTE
AS(
    SELECT sched.name AS 'scheduleName'
        , sched.schedule_id
        , jobsched.job_id
        , CASE 
            WHEN sched.freq_type = 1 
                THEN 'Once' 
            WHEN sched.freq_type = 4 
                AND sched.freq_interval = 1 
                    THEN 'Daily'
            WHEN sched.freq_type = 4 
                THEN 'Every ' + CAST(sched.freq_interval AS VARCHAR(5)) + '     days'
            WHEN sched.freq_type = 8 THEN 
                REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE(( 
                    SELECT maskValue 
                    FROM @weekDay AS x 
                    WHERE sched.freq_interval & x.mask <> 0 
                    ORDER BY mask FOR XML RAW)
                , '"/><row maskValue="', ', '), '<row     maskValue="', ''), '"/>', '') 
                + CASE 
                    WHEN sched.freq_recurrence_factor <> 0 
                        AND sched.freq_recurrence_factor = 1 
                            THEN '; weekly' 
                    WHEN sched.freq_recurrence_factor <> 0 
                        THEN '; every ' 
                + CAST(sched.freq_recurrence_factor AS VARCHAR(10)) + '     weeks' END
            WHEN sched.freq_type = 16 THEN 'On day ' 
                + CAST(sched.freq_interval AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' of every '
                + CAST(sched.freq_recurrence_factor AS VARCHAR(10)) + '     months' 
            WHEN sched.freq_type = 32 THEN 
                CASE 
                    WHEN sched.freq_relative_interval = 1 THEN 'First'
                    WHEN sched.freq_relative_interval = 2 THEN 'Second'
                    WHEN sched.freq_relative_interval = 4 THEN 'Third'
                    WHEN sched.freq_relative_interval = 8 THEN 'Fourth'
                    WHEN sched.freq_relative_interval = 16 THEN 'Last'
                END + 
                CASE 
                    WHEN sched.freq_interval = 1 THEN ' Sunday'
                    WHEN sched.freq_interval = 2 THEN ' Monday'
                    WHEN sched.freq_interval = 3 THEN ' Tuesday'
                    WHEN sched.freq_interval = 4 THEN ' Wednesday'
                    WHEN sched.freq_interval = 5 THEN ' Thursday'
                    WHEN sched.freq_interval = 6 THEN ' Friday'
                    WHEN sched.freq_interval = 7 THEN ' Saturday'
                    WHEN sched.freq_interval = 8 THEN ' Day'
                    WHEN sched.freq_interval = 9 THEN ' Weekday'
                    WHEN sched.freq_interval = 10 THEN ' Weekend'
                END
                + CASE 
                    WHEN sched.freq_recurrence_factor <> 0 
                        AND sched.freq_recurrence_factor = 1 
                            THEN '; monthly'
                    WHEN sched.freq_recurrence_factor <> 0 
                        THEN '; every ' 
                + CAST(sched.freq_recurrence_factor AS VARCHAR(10)) + '     months' 
                  END
            WHEN sched.freq_type = 64   THEN 'StartUp'
            WHEN sched.freq_type = 128  THEN 'Idle'
          END AS 'frequency'
        , ISNULL('Every ' + CAST(sched.freq_subday_interval AS VARCHAR(10))     + 
            CASE 
                WHEN sched.freq_subday_type = 2 THEN ' seconds'
                WHEN sched.freq_subday_type = 4 THEN ' minutes'
                WHEN sched.freq_subday_type = 8 THEN ' hours'
            END, 'Once') AS 'subFrequency'
        , REPLICATE('0', 6 - LEN(sched.active_start_time)) 
            + CAST(sched.active_start_time AS VARCHAR(6)) AS 'startTime'
        , REPLICATE('0', 6 - LEN(sched.active_end_time)) 
            + CAST(sched.active_end_time AS VARCHAR(6)) AS 'endTime'
        , REPLICATE('0', 6 - LEN(jobsched.next_run_time)) 
            + CAST(jobsched.next_run_time AS VARCHAR(6)) AS 'nextRunTime'
        , CAST(jobsched.next_run_date AS CHAR(8)) AS 'nextRunDate'
    FROM msdb.dbo.sysschedules      AS sched
    JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules   AS jobsched
        ON sched.schedule_id = jobsched.schedule_id
    WHERE sched.enabled = 1
)

SELECT job.name                                                         AS     [Job Name]
    , CASE WHEN job.enabled = 1 THEN 'Enabled' ELSE 'Disabled' END      AS     [Job Status]
    , COALESCE(sched.subFrequency, '')                                  AS     [Frequency]
    , COALESCE(jh.last_duration, '')                                        AS [Last Run Duration]
    , COALESCE(jh.last_execution_start, '')                                 AS [Last Run Time/Date]
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs               AS job
LEFT JOIN myCTE                     AS sched
    ON job.job_id = sched.job_id
LEFT JOIN @jobHistory               AS jh
    ON job.job_id = jh.job_id
WHERE jh.last_execution_start >= DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
    AND job.name like '%MAINTENANCE - BACKUP%'
    ORDER BY nextRunDate;
```

but although the results show the expected 'Failed' jobs, the 'Disabled' jobs are missing. I have also had help with this, as I have no SQL experience.

This Query has been created to check the Job History of roughtly 5/10 Backup Jobs within a 24 hour period, noting all the Failures (even if the last Run Succeeded). The seconds on the [Last Run Time/Date] also seem to be off, showing as soemthign like '50:00.0'

I also need a new column for the [Last Run Outcome] - to show if the Job 'Failed/Succeeded' as a Status.

Please let me know if you require any further information or a PasteBin of my code.

Comment: you are doing a left join against myCTE, which has a `WHERE sched.enabled = 1` set. And I see `Disabled` happens when `job.enabled` is not 1...

Comment: Here is a [LINK](http://pastebin.com/AHTCSHZY) to a dump fo the Results produced by this Query

Comment: @fedorqui I see, to be honest, this can be left excluding the Disabled jobs. I don't suppose you know how to add in the additional [Last Run Outcome] to show whether the Job 'Failed' or 'Succeeded'? And possibly a [Next Run Time/Date]? The issue witht he Seconds is due to the export to Excel and the cell formats, so please excuse this!

Comment: @fedorqui The 'job.enabled' you mentione above, seems to relay 'text' based on the result, not the excual result. If I change 'Enabled' to be 'Yes' and 'Disabled' to say 'No', this replaces the wording. I'd prefer this to just relay the status as it is.

Comment: You are entering into details that are too specific. Try to provide a [mcve] instead. What I would suggest is to comment out the `WHERE sched.enabled = 1` and see if things change.

Comment: Thank you @fedorqui, not sure if a previous Question of mine explains what I'm trying to achieve as a whole in a bit more detail - [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40155737/sql-query-to-report-on-backup-job-failures)

Comment: @fedorqui commenting this out produces the same results. Will take a look over the weekend. Struggling to explain what I'm after with no SQL experience, seems I need to sit down with somebody lol really appreciate the advice/help though!

Comment: That's a shame! I suggest you to narrow down the problem by getting into a very simple query that works and then expand it. Otherwise, this huge query will drive you crazy.